# Startup.cs is not showing in Visual Studio 2022? where can I find

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I need to add DbContext in startup.cs, Can any one suggest

[DbContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSYer.png)

Comment: "I need to add DbContext in startup.cs" - no, you presumably need to add a DbContext *somewhere*. That doesn't have to be in a file called Startup.cs. I suspect if you look in Program.cs you'll find the DI configuration you're looking for.

Comment: Could you please share you code instead of screenshot. Please share [`minimum reproducible code`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: While I'd normally agree, in this case the question really is about "why is the file I expected not there" (and it's basically because the default structure of ASP.NET Core apps has changed over time).

Comment: @JonSkeet My guru, yes I think so, he probably want to know how to initialize the context in `program.cs` so I am interest to know more details.

Comment: If you are `using asp.net core 6 or above` it doesn't have `startup.cs` instead it has `program.cs` where you can initialize your `database context`. You can have a look on this [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: read documentation or first search your problem on google.

Comment: Please put your code into the post directly and not as an image. That way others can see directly what your question is about and copy/paste the code for debugging. Makes helping more easy!

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a Startup class for that you can do that directly from Program.cs

Something like this :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = "your connection string";
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```